# For every natural number $x$, $\frac{1}{x} \le 1$

Tags: proof-verification

I am quite new to proofs, and I tried solving this proof myself. Here is what I got:

let $x$ be a natural number
Suppose $\frac{1}{x} > 1$, then $1 > x  $
This is a contradiction because x cannot equal $0$ and $x$ must be greater than $0$.

Therefore, For every natural number $x$, $\frac{1}{x}\le 1$

I do not know if this valid, But I tried using proof by contradiction. Is this the correct way of doing it? or am I wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: One thing to be careful of: In some conventions, $0$ is a natural number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $1/x>1$, then multiplication with natural number $x\geq 1$ (multiplication with $x>0$ is monotonous) yields $1>x$ which is a contradiction.
Thus $1/x>1$ is false, i.e., $1/x\leq 1$ is true.

Comment: Thanks for the verification! Proofs are really confusing me and I wasn't sure if what I did was correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are right 
Because
you cannot change sides of the terms in inequalities , 
like equations when they divide each other.

$$\frac1x<1 \implies 1\lt x$$
(This is not applicable for the inequalities.)